# Azure - Why can I not upload an SSL certificate?

Tags: azure, ssl

Question Background:

I am trying to upload an SSL certificate to Azure for my web app.

The Issue:

I located the SSL Certificate option within the settings and the following is shown.

There should be an option to upload my own SSL certificate but this is not present, why not?

[image]

Comment: An SSL *certificate.* There is no such thing as 'an SSL'. Off topic.

Comment: do you have a basic plan or higher?

Comment: @EJP, an honest mistake I do apologies.......

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you. I have since found out that you're only able to setup an SSL certificate with a plan of basic plan or higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure App Service, you can only configure SSL on a custom domain if you are on a Basic pricing plan or Higher. The Free and Shared pricing plans do not support SSL configuration with custom domains.